# Microsoft Luis API is getting slow after new endpoint

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

My new luis api endpoint is https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v1.
Is this endpoint correct?

Since 10-March-2017, I am experiencing the slowness in the LUIS API.

Can anyone tell me the reason of slowness? or Do I need to do any update in my api or endpoint?

Thanks

Comment: The question is too broad, it's impossible to know why the service is being slow in your end; it could be your internet connection and/or many other things. The only thing I can suggest you to see if it changes something is to use the v2 endpoint as the v1 is kind of deprecated. So instead of https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v1 use https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0

Comment: Thank you @EzequielJadib. When I create new luis cognitive service in azure account, it is creating V1 as endpoint default. How can I change that from Azure? Can you guide me?

Comment: You can just use the updated URL that @EzequielJadib mentioned.  The Azure portal is still being updated to suggest the new endpoint.  New or old will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they stated that it would happen at https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-US/subscriptions saying "Starting on 1/17, our endpoints will be changing. If your API is currently using "api.projectoxford.ai" endpoint, you will need to switch to the new API endpoint starting on 1/17. If you continue to use the legacy endpoint after 1/17, you may experience latency. To know if you are affected, visit your API homepage and click on the “API Reference” button for more information on your API’s endpoint change. We thank you for your cooperation as we continue to improve our services. The old API endpoints will be deprecated 90 days following this change (on 4/15)."

Comment: May I know how can I change endpoint? if I create new cognitive service luis api in azure, it is always create by pointing v1 as endpoint.

Comment: You should be able to use the V2 endpoint, there aren't different keys for that.  That said, I wouldn't expect a performance difference.  Please confirm if you do see one.

Comment: you get the endpoint in your luis website / my apps / your app / publish app / endpoint url